# Do you need to install the CORS module on IIS 10?

Tags: iis, cors

I have read articles about enabling CORS on IIS, but on older versions they don't mention the CORS module that needs to be installed.

Normally, you can click on the Response Headers icon and add headers without any warnings about a CORS module. Has something changed?

Do you only need to install the CORS module on IIS 10 or do you need it on all versions of IIS?

Do you need to do an IISReset after adding headers in the web.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is a mechanism to let a user-agent access resources from a domain outside of the domain from which the first resource was served.

You can enable cors click Response Headers icon; If you want to use this feature, I suggest you install this module no matter what version of IIS; After reconfiguring the website hosted in IIS, you can restart and clear the browser cache to check whether the new feature changes are applied.